# Can i use multiple licenses in my free project?

Tags: licensing

I will plan write project for portfolio for free use with no modifying source code of dependencies and publish it on github. Dependencies is openjdk (gplv2+cpe), spring (apache 2.0), hibernate (LGPL 2.1), postgresql (under own license postgresql lisence) and angular (mit). Can i use it together in one project and which type of final license i should use for this project?

Comment: I not plan to change license of spring or hibernate, i just want use it in my own project under GPLv3 with calling and dependecies (not changing of source code). I read there is no problem with it cause openjdk use GPLv2 with CPE and Hibernate use LGPL 2.1. I think rightly?

Comment: That's problematic to distribute the resulting binary: GPL (as required by OpenJDK) is incompatible with Apache (Spring). As such no-one may distribute the compiled version. Take this with a grain of salt as I'm not into the Java environment at all and cannot properly judge how things depend on eachother and to what degree they interoperate.

Comment: @planetmaker As a fellow Java-ignorant person, I will point out that the classpath exception (the "+CPE" in the question) effectively makes the GPL into the LGPL (though [not exactly](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/what-is-the-difference-between-gpl-classpath-exception-vs-lgpl)) for linking purposes. I don't know for sure whether that solves the issue, but it looks promising.

Answer (score -1):

OpenJDK is licensed under the GNU GPL, therefore you must use the GNU GPL.

The other libraries you listed are licensed under GNU GPL-compatible licenses, except for Spring, licensed under Apache 2.0, incompatible with the GNU GPLv2.

So you should use the GNU GPL, but do not use Spring.

Comment: what about the class path exception? How does that impact your answer?

Comment: That comment does not equate. The license terms don't make a difference on the use case and the chosen license of a project and apply equally. And as OpenJDK is licensed under GPL with CPE... that does make a difference (see comment to original question by apsillers)

Comment: OpenJDK can be used in projects licensed under the GNU GPL or a stronger license. But it cannot be used in projects licensed under a weaker license then the GNU GPL, unless it is a GNU GPL-compatible license. MIT is GPL-compatible but not Apache 2.0, so you still have to remove Spring.

Comment: I think you mis-understand the implication of the CPE in OpenJDK's license. See https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/what-is-the-difference-between-gpl-classpath-exception-vs-lgpl for a brief take on the implication

Comment: JNIC, please read same questions https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7971/java-openjdk-11-and-spring-licenses https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/11038/openjdk-gplv2cpe-and-spring-apache-2-0-can-i-use-them-together